# NotImplementedError: float16 indexes are not supported

Tags: python, pandas

I just upgraded to use pandas 2. Then I got this below error for the below code. I was using float16 in order to reduce memory use before without any problem. Where is the problem? Does pandas 2 doesn't allow using float16? before pandas 2, the code was fine.

```
file='test_read_float16.csv'

df=pd.read_csv(file,sep='\t')
df
Depth   2023-05-12  2023-05-12 0:20 2023-05-12 0:36
0   0   19.593750   19.296875   20.59375
1   1   23.296875   21.906250   21.00000
2   2   112.187500  112.187500  111.68750
3   3   180.750000  180.750000  180.25000
4   4   187.375000  188.500000  188.12500
```

```
df=df.astype('float16',errors='ignore')
df=df.set_index('Depth')
df

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
cnrl\users\yongnual\Data\Spyder_workplace\DTS_dashboard\DTS_dashboard_v201_injectorDateRange_reducememory_seeqcrossplot_calcfluidlevel_crossplotseeq_crossplotspm_b12dtscrossplot_pandas2_parquet.ipynb Cell 205 line 2
      1 df=df.astype('float16',errors='ignore')
----> 2 df=df.set_index('Depth')
      3 df

File c:\Anaconda\envs\dash2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:5915, in DataFrame.set_index(self, keys, drop, append, inplace, verify_integrity)
   5907     if len(arrays[-1]) != len(self):
   5908         # check newest element against length of calling frame, since
   5909         # ensure_index_from_sequences would not raise for append=False.
   5910         raise ValueError(
   5911             f"Length mismatch: Expected {len(self)} rows, "
   5912             f"received array of length {len(arrays[-1])}"
   5913         )
-> 5915 index = ensure_index_from_sequences(arrays, names)
   5917 if verify_integrity and not index.is_unique:
   5918     duplicates = index[index.duplicated()].unique()

File c:\Anaconda\envs\dash2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:7067, in ensure_index_from_sequences(sequences, names)
   7065     if names is not None:
   7066         names = names[0]
-> 7067     return Index(sequences[0], name=names)
   7068 else:
   7069     return MultiIndex.from_arrays(sequences, names=names)
...
    578     # asarray_tuplesafe does not always copy underlying data,
    579     #  so need to make sure that this happens
    580     data = data.copy()

NotImplementedError: float16 indexes are not supported
```

Comment: Pandas 2 does allow `float16`, but it does not allow `float16` indexes.

Comment: Thanks Michale. why not float16 for index? just curious. Thanks

Comment: No explanation why in the [release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#index-can-now-hold-numpy-numeric-dtypes). It just says "Index cannot be instantiated using a float16 dtype. Previously instantiating an Index using dtype float16 resulted in a Float64Index with a float64 dtype. It now raises a NotImplementedError"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [*Matthew Roeschke*](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/7716#issuecomment-1498160636) :

> [`pd.Index`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9220#issuecomment-1258536212) intentionally does not support `np.float16` as dtype anymore.
> **We never had an indexing engine for this dtype.**

I understand there isn't yet an [*indexing mechanism*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/89bd5695df3ccf5b9186b4645118656656831593/pandas/_libs/index.pyi#L10) that could handle this data type within pandas.

As of `2.1.1`, here is a list of all the [`numeric engines`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/89bd5695df3ccf5b9186b4645118656656831593/asv_bench/benchmarks/indexing_engines.py#L19) :

```
[
    ("Int64Engine", np.int64),
    ("Int32Engine", np.int32),
    ("Int16Engine", np.int16),
    ("Int8Engine", np.int8),
    ("UInt64Engine", np.uint64),
    ("UInt32Engine", np.uint32),
    ("UInt16engine", np.uint16),
    ("UInt8Engine", np.uint8),
    ("Float64Engine", np.float64),
    ("Float32Engine", np.float32),
]
```

Comment: I'm surprised that they didn't convert `float16` to a `float32` index automatically, or a `float64` index as was done in previous versions.